# mysql adding column based on number of elements

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a mysql table of users and one of certain attributes.

I've got a third table to combines the two (user with X number of attributes). Each attribute is a separate element/column.

My question is; if I have a user that has X number of elements, and another user that has X+1 number of elements, how can I tell the database to add +1 (or any number of columns as needed) to the table?

Would be it something along these lines?

```
if(table_columns < attribute_columns)
{
mysqli_query($db,"ADD 'X amount' NEW COLUMN && ADD attributes");
}
else
{
mysqli_query($db,"ADD attributes");
}
```

Just wanted to clarify that I'm on the right track, or if I'm going about things the wrong way.

Comment: in this scanrio simple create a table with for example 5 fields. User 1 has 3 fields others should be null. and the other user will have all the fields. This is how it should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the proper way to do what it appears you are trying to do. This is how it is normally done:
 Users Table: UserID, name, other things you might want...
 Attributes Table: AttID, name, other things you might want...
 UserAttributes Table: UserID, AttID, AttValue

You will constrain UserAttributes.UserID as a foreign key on Users.UserID. You will constrain UserAttributes.AttID as a foreign key on Attributes.AttID. To get a list of attributes for a user, you use: select u.name as username, a.name as attname, ua.attvalue as attvalue from users u join userattributes ua on u.userid=ua.userid join attributes a on ua.attid=a.attid where u.userid = USER_ID_TO_LOOK_FOR

Comment: Do you know if there is some documentation or a tutorial I can read? Or some search keywords I can type in to get to the right location.

Comment: It is commonly called a mapping table. It is used for a many-to-many relationship between two sets. Typing "mapping table" into google brought up a lot of articles about how and why to use mapping tables.